# Class method doesn't return anything

Tags: python, python-3.2

I'm having problems calling(accessing?) the methods in my class

```
class dag(object):

    def __init__(self,temp):
        self.name = temp[3]
        self.l_o_t = temp

    def __str__(self):

        print ("The hottest temperature was:",self.l_o_t[0])
        print ("The coolest temperature was:",self.l_o_t[1])
        print ("The average temperature was:",self.l_o_t[2])

    def returnmax(self):

        return self.l_o_t[0]
    def returnmin(self):
        return self.l_o_t[1]
    def returnavg(self):
        return self.l_o_t[2]


def main():
    temp = dag(list_of_temperatures)
    temp.returnmax()
    temp.returnmin()
    temp.returnavg()
    temp.__str__()
```

When trying to print out the value that `returnmax`, `returnmin`, `returnavg` return the main program doesn't print anything. Only print statements, as in the **str** method seem to work, why is that?

Answer (score 4):

The Python interactive interpreter echos everything for you because it is an interactive debugger, but in a Python program you need to *explicitly* print values.

Add `print()` calls to show the return values:

```
temp = dag(list_of_temperatures)
print(temp.returnmax())
print(temp.returnmin())
print(temp.returnavg())
```

Normally, a `__str__` method would return a string value, *not* use `print()` in the method:

```
def __str__(self):
    value = (
        'The hottest temperature was: {0.l_o_t[0]}\n'
        'The coolest temperature was: {0.l_o_t[1]}\n'
        'The average temperature was: {0.l_o_t[2]}\n'
    ).format(self)
    return value
```

and then you'd use `print()`, which would call `str()` on the value, which in turn calls the `__str__()` method:

```
print(temp)
```

Comment: It's not the same for regular functions right? There you dont have to use print to call the function value?

Comment: @user3221453: *Anywhere* you want to produce output to your terminal you'd need to explicitly use `print()`.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the modifications you did to my __str__ method, the .format(self) generates the following error :
  
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @user3221453: ah, I should have included an index there. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

`str(obj)` will call `def __str__(self)` function,so **str** function need return a value,not print a value

when function returns a value but you forget to print, you can't see it

It is not the same as shell

```
class dag(object):

    def __init__(self,temp):
        self.name = temp[3]
        self.l_o_t = temp

    def __str__(self):
        a = "The hottest temperature was:%s"%self.l_o_t[0]
        b = "The coolest temperature was:%s"%self.l_o_t[1]
        c = "The average temperature was:%s"%self.l_o_t[2]
        return '\n'.join([a,b,c])

    def returnmax(self):
        return self.l_o_t[0]
    def returnmin(self):
        return self.l_o_t[1]
    def returnavg(self):
        return self.l_o_t[2]


def main():
    temp = dag([27,19,23,'DAG'])
    print(temp.returnmax())
    print(temp.returnmin())
    print(temp.returnavg())
    print(temp) # print will call str, that is __str__


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what you did. It's difficult for a reader to go line-by-line trying to see what you did differently.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,Bryan Oakley!